# Clicking on a specific coordinate (return TRUE or FALSE)?

Tags: javascript

I want my function to be able to take a rectangle coord. system and return true or false as to whether the mouse was clicked inside of the region.

This should set up a region for the user to click with the top upper corner being in1X, in1Y and in2X, in2Y.

```
       if ((event.clientX  >= in1X && event.clientX  <= in2X) &&
            (event.clientY >= in1Y && event.clientY  <= in2Y)) {
                context.font = "20px Arial";
                context.fillText("Click Me",100,300);
       }
```

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas  = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
      context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 1;
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();

      var mouseIsDown = false;

        canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
            var Test1X,Test1Y;
            Test1X = 20;
            Test1Y = 20;

            var Test2X,Test2Y;
            Test2X = 100;
            Test2Y = 100;

            CheckIfInCoord(Test1X,Test1Y,Test2X,Test2Y,e);

            mouseIsDown = true;
        }
        canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
            if(mouseIsDown) {
                mouseClick(e);
            }

            mouseIsDown = false;
        }

        canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
            if(!mouseIsDown) {
                return;
            }

            return false;
        }

        //mouse click is both a onmouseup and onmousedown
        function mouseClick(e){
            context.font = "20px Arial";
            context.fillText("Should be in Square",10,150);
        }

        function CheckIfInCoord(in1X,in1Y,in2X,in2Y,event) {
            console.log(event.x);
            console.log(event.y);
              console.log("--");
            console.log(in1X);
            console.log(in2X);

            if (event.clientX  >= in1X) {
                    context.font = "20px Arial";
                    context.fillText("Click Me",100,300);
            }


        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Actually it appears to work on maybe the first click but will then if clicked again print Click to the screen.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/doughauf/dnx85rva/

Comment: I want my computer making pizza for me!
What is your question here, is there an error, does it simply "not work"? Also always helpful create a jsfiddle.

Comment: That is true. i do have a JSFidle account. I will see about putting one up in the am tomorrow or when I get off work. Basically what I want is for the user only be able to click inside of the rectangle to trigger some kind of action inside of the canvas. I want to make a generic function that ca be used to test any sized location inside of the canvas I am going to use it inside of a game.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use event.clientX / event.clientY instead of event.x / event.y

Comment: If you can look at the fiddle to see what the example does I would appreciate it. I do not think that it should be that difficult.

Comment: I looked at your fiddle account. It seems work fine (when I click inside the box, it says 'click me' and 'Nope! Not working' for outside of the box).

Is this the answer you want or you expected anything different?

Answer (score 0):

I change your code on the fiddle to read like below. this seems to work but I did notice that on some occasions on the first click that it was giving garbage but then would work if the page was refreshed.

Let me know if you need more work done on this.

---

```
  var canvas  = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
  context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
  context.fill();
  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.strokeStyle = 'black';
  context.stroke();

  var mouseIsDown = false;

    canvas.onmousedown = function(e){
        var Test1X,Test1Y;
        Test1X = 20;
        Test1Y = 20;

        var Test2X,Test2Y;
        Test2X = 100;
        Test2Y = 100;

        CheckIfInCoord(Test1X,Test1Y,Test2X,Test2Y,e);

        mouseIsDown = true;
    }

    canvas.onmouseup = function(e){
        if(mouseIsDown) {
            mouseClick(e);
        }

        mouseIsDown = false;
    }

    canvas.onmousemove = function(e){
        if(!mouseIsDown) {
            return;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function mouseClick(e){
    }

    function CheckIfInCoord(in1X,in1Y,in2X,in2Y,event) {
        if ((event.clientX  >= in1X && event.clientX  <= in2X) &&
            (event.clientY  >= in1Y && event.clientY  <= in2Y)) {
                context.fillStyle    = 'white';
                context.font = "20px Arial";
                context.fillText("Out of box",200,300);

                context.fillStyle    = 'red';
                context.font = "20px Arial";
                context.fillText("In box",100,300);
        } else {
            context.fillStyle    = 'white';
            context.font = "20px Arial";
            context.fillText("In box",100,300);

            context.fillStyle    = 'red';
            context.font = "20px Arial";
            context.fillText("Out of box ",200,300);
        }
    }
```

---